# Limitar caracteres despues de un punto?

Tags: javascript, html

Como puedo limitar los caracteres despues de un punto? Cuando realizo la resta de mi descuento los valores despues del punto se disparan, pense en un maxlength  pero no estoy seguro.
[image: Form]

```
$('#txtImporteD').on('change', function() {   
    var tip = $('#selTipoD option:selected').attr("value");
    var imp = $("#txtSubTotal").val();
    var descuento = $("#txtImporteD").val();
    var x = imp - descuento;
    var desc = (descuento*imp/100);
    var y = imp - desc;
    if (tip=="1") {
        $("#txtTotal").val(x);
    }else if (tip=="2") {
        $("#txtTotal").val(y);
    }
});
```

Comment: tal como te respondieron usa "toFixed" donde determinas el numero de decimales deseados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí solo requieres imprimirlo, o colocarlo como mensaje sería:

```
x.toFixed(2);
y.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar Fixed

```
$("#txtTotal").val(x).fixed(2); // 2 indica cuantos decimales quieres mostrar
```

Te adjunto un enlace
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp